# SoX: How to noise gate?

Tags: audio, sox, audacity

audacity has a noise gate plugin that works nicely. I am looking for a command line equivalent - but am unable to figure out SoX compand command to do it. Could anyone tell me the sox equivalent of audacity noise gate ? For example, I use in audacity 
"Gate frequencies above: 0.0", level reduction: -12, Gate Threshold -48.0, Attack/Decay 250.0 ?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the `compand` command in SOX?  See http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html, scroll down to the section for the `compand` command, and see where it says:

```
In the next example, compand is being used as a noise-gate for when the noise is at 
a lower level than the signal:
play infile compand .1,.2 −inf,−50.1,−inf,−50,−50 0 −90 .1
```

Comment: It's embarassing - but I did try, but unable to understand the manual.

Answer (score 1):

From the [sox man page](http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html), you can hack the [compand dynamic range compressor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_range_compression) to only gate the noise

```
sox infile outfile compand .1,.2 −inf,−50.1,−inf,−50,−50 0 −90 .1
```

breaking down the format:

```
.1,.2
attack1,decay1{,attack2,decay2}
```

attack and decay are set to small values of .1 and .2, which basically sets the window size.

```
−inf,−50.1,−inf,−50,−50
[soft-knee-dB:]in-dB1[,out-dB1]{,in-dB2,out-dB2}
```

this is where we define the noise gate, negative infinity for the soft knee, in dB set to -50.1, negative infinity for the out, then -50 dB and -50 dB. This is where you adjust the gate level. If you want to remove more noise change the value to 30 dB:

```
−inf,−30.1,−inf,−30,−30
```

if the gate is too large and it is clipping content, then lower the gate threshold to 70 dB:

```
−inf,−70.1,−inf,−70,−70
```

in the last part

```
0 −90 .1
[gain [initial-volume-dB [delay]]]
```

finally we set the gain to 0, initial volume to -90 dB, and the delay to 0.1 sec.

I think many people (including myself) do not have a firm grasp on the compand parameters, [see for example](https://forum.doom9.org/showthread.php?t=165807).

Answer (score -2):

```
sox noise.wav -n noiseprof | play sound.wav noisered
```

will do noise gating as audacity does.